# Mongoose: find mixed schema type documents with multiple entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My data model looks roughly like this:

```
data = {
    ...
    parameters: [{type:Schema.Types.mixed}],
    ...
}
```

If i now insert a document into the database,

```
doc = {
  ...
  parameters:[{"foo":"bar"}],
  ...
}
```

i can query it via the "parameters" key:

```
db.dataset.find({"parameters":[{"foo":"bar"}]},function(doc){
  ...
})
```

and get back the expected document. However if "parameters" contains more than one key, for example

```
doc = {
  ...
  parameters:[{"foo":"bar","ding":"dong"}]
  ...
}
```

i cant find it anymore. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the query cannot match any documents where the array field `parameters` has the exact array object as its value `[{"foo":  "bar", "ding": "dong"}]`. To demonstrate this, let's insert a couple of sample documents in a collection:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551d777fcfd33f4e2a61e48f"),
    "parameters" : [ 
        {
            "foo" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551d777fcfd33f4e2a61e490"),
    "parameters" : [ 
        {
            "foo" : "bar",
            "ding" : "dong"
        }
    ]
}
```

Querying this collection for `parameters` array with this object array `[{"foo":"bar"}]` will bring the document with "_id" : `ObjectId("551d777fcfd33f4e2a61e48f")`. However, if you change your query object to use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) then it will bring both documents:

```
db.collection.find({"parameters": { "$elemMatch": { "foo": "bar" } }});
```