# Unable to get the value of particular key in mongoose if that key is not present in Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
UserEventsInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    event_movie:[String],
    event_tour:[String],
    event_restaurant:[String],
    event_lifetimeevents:[String]
},{strict : false});
```

I am able to insert new key-value pair other than defined in the schema

but when I try to read the value of that key. I can't. I am using the following code.

```
UserEventsDetails.find({username:username},function(err,docs){
  if(!docs.length)
  {
    res.send('datanotavailable');
      }
  else{
    res.send(docs[0][eventname]);
        }
  });
```

Here **eventname** is a variable.
When I add that key in the schema it returns the value i.e. work's fine.
Otherwise it is not returning any value.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any thing - it just returns only those keys that are present in the schema

Comment: console.log(err) in the callback function, may help you...

Comment: If the key is not present, the err is null, and the docs is `[]` one empty array

Comment: console.log(docs[0]["eventname"]);  is giving me undefined

Comment: when I add "eventname" in schema - it returns the array value

Comment: It seems `eventname` is missing in your schema, whereas, this field exist in your db?

Comment: Yes, eventname is not there in the schema but can i get the key without that because that key was added laterly dynamically in the database

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/196) submitted like this to mongoose. Here is there response:

> The benefit we see in a schemaless database is the ability for our data model to evolve as fast as our features require it, without a linear impact on performance and slower deployment cycles with needless migrations.
>
> If you don't want your data to be normalized and validated prior to saving, then you don't need a tool like Mongoose, you can use the driver directly.

After a little digging there is a way to do this, but you will need to have a field with type `Schema.Types.Mixed`. So it would look like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    mixed: Schema.Types.Mixed,
});

var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', schema);

var m = new Thing;
m.mixed = { any: { thing: 'i want' } };

m.save(callback);
```

To do a find on a mixed this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418261/mongoose-find-mixed-schema-type-documents-with-multiple-entries) answers that.

****EDIT

forgot to link the documentation of [mixed types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)